# GitHub detected vulnerability in dependency, but I ran npm update and the dependency didn't update?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

On a push to GitHub, I got this message:

> GitHub found 1 vulnerability on username/projectname's default branch (1 moderate).

I checked the project on Github and discovered that I need to update Sequelize to 5.3.0.  Locally, I ran `npm update` and another one of my packages updated, but Sequelize didn't update.

I committed, then pushed to Github again, and got the same vulnerability warning.  I checked `package.json` and it shows the following under dependencies:

```
"sequelize": "^4.43.1"
```

Is there something different I need to do to update Sequelize?  Or at least to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html) respects [caret dependency restrictions](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html#caret-dependencies) in `package.json`. You are asking for version `"^4.43.1"`, [meaning the latest version available without updating the leftmost nonzero digit](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004). The latest `4.x.y` version of `sequelize` is `4.43.1`.

Update its major version in `package.json`, e.g. to `^5.3.0` since that's what you know you need, then run `npm update` again. This should give you the latest release with major version `5` (`5.3.5` at the time of writing). It will also update both your `package.json` and your `package-lock.json`.